# Why is transformer decoder always generating output of same length as gold labels?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, encoder-decoder

I am generating some summaries using a fine-tuned BART model, and I've noticed something strange. If I feed the labels to the model, it will always generate summaries of the same length of the label, whereas if I do not pass the labels to the model, it generates outputs of length 1024 (max BART seq length). This is unexpected, so I'm trying to understand if there is any problem / bug with the reproducible example below

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoTokenizer
model=AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-large-cnn')
tokenizer=AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-large-cnn')


sentence_to_summarize = ['This is a text to summarise. I just went for a walk in the park and saw very large crowds gathering to watch an impromptu football match']
encoded_dict = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(sentence_to_summarize, return_tensors='pt', max_length=1024, padding='max_length')
input_ids = encoded_dict['input_ids']
attention_mask = encoded_dict['attention_mask']
label = tokenizer.encode('I went to the park', return_tensors='pt')
```

Notice the following two cases.
Case 1:

```
output = model(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
print(output['logits'].shape)
```

shape printed is `torch.Size([1, 1024, 50264])`

Case 2

```
output = model(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=label)
print(output['logits'].shape)
```

shape printed is `torch.Size([1, 7, 50264])` where 7 is the length of the label `'I went to the park'` (including start and end tokens).
Ideally the summarization model would learn when to generate the EOS token, but this should not always lead to summaries of identical length of the gold output (i.e. the label). Why is the label length influencing the model output in this way?

I would expect the only difference between cases 1 and 2 being that in the second case the output also contains the loss value, but I wouldn't expect this to influence the logits in any way

Answer (score -1):

Original example not use label parameter

https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.22.1/en/model_doc/bart#transformers.BartForConditionalGeneration.forward.example

label parameter is optional and i think not used for summerizing

https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.22.1/en/model_doc/bart#transformers.BartForConditionalGeneration.forward.labels

Comment: Hi, I see your point, however the fact that something is not used in the original example doesn't really prove much or answer my question. The examples are usually made with some common parameters for certain use cases, but it doesn't mean that using different parameters is wrong. The fact that the label parameter is optional also doesn't mean that I will get different results based on whether I use it or not, as the only difference should be that the loss is also returned when I pass the labels. If you happen to know why I get different results when passing labels please let me know

Comment: Model is general Seq2SeqLM not only with summarizing . Label parameter it hinik not used for summarizing. See SummarizationPipeline
https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.22.1/en/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.SummarizationPipeline